# CUDA: addresses to global memory stored in array

Tags: arrays, memory, cuda

I am trying to implement a small project in CUDA. The initial data sets are:

- an array (`pos`) with addresses (positions as unsigned integers)
- another array (`data`) which has to be accessed based on the addresses stored in the first array)
- an array (`res`) which will contain the results of some computation (for this example, it will only write the value 1 in all elements, to verify data coherency).

The following program:

```
__global__ 
void testKernel (unsigned int *res, const unsigned int *data, unsigned int *pos)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int x = pos[idx];   
    int foo = data[x];          // if I take out this line it works properly
    res[idx] = 1;
}
```

ends up in writing strange values in the `res` array (similar to the ones stored in `data`) rather than 1.

The invocation looks something like this:

```
#define WIDTH = 500
#define BLK_SIZE = 64
void main() {
    int blockSize = BLK_SIZE;
    int nBlocks = (WIDTH + BLK_SIZE - 1) / blockSize;

    // memory allocations: res[WIDTH]; data[DATA_WIDTH]; pos[WIDTH]
    // sanity checks for positions 
    // H2D memory transfers
    testKernel <<<nBlocks,blockSize>>>(res_d, data_d, pos_d);
    // D2H memory transfers
    // free memory
}
```

Right now I am using global memory for everything, since I am trying to reach an initial implementation. The memory allocations, transfers and the kernel invocation are correct.

Is there another way to properly solve this task? If so, what caused the strange results?

Comment: could you add a couple of missing information? `WIDTH` value and kernel invocation line. And N_SAMPLES.

Comment: I added the requested information.

Comment: I realized that there is a lot of useless information in the code. I will try to reduce the problem so that it becomes relevant.

Comment: it was clear before I think... now I'm not sure anymore :) see if the answer fit it by yourself - revert the last edit maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since `WIDTH` is not divisable by `BLK_SIZE` you have to insert an if in your code that exclude out-of-bound indeces:

```
__global__ 
void testKernel (unsigned int *res, const unsigned int *data, unsigned int *pos)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (idx < WIDTH) {
       ...
    }
}
```

In fact `idx` is going from 0 to 512 in your kernel, in blocks of 32 (warp size), independently on the `blockDim` that you have specified (that in this case is multiple, so this is not the issue here).

Comment: Yes, you are right. A typical mistake and it seems it wasn't a problem related to stored addresses. It tried to access data locations which were not allocated. Thank you!